# Aligning a text box edge with an image corner

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way of exactly aligning (overlaying) the corner edge of my image with corner and edge of a text box edge (bbox or other)

The code in question is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(np.random.random((256,256)), cmap=plt.get_cmap("viridis"))
ax.axis("off")

ax.annotate(
    s = 'image title', 
    xy=(0, 0), 
    xytext=(0, 0), 
    va='top',
    ha='left',
    fontsize = 15,
    bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=1),
    )
plt.show()
```

[image: Single image]

As you can see, the edges of the text box is outside the image. For the life of me, I cannot find a consistent way of aligning the corner of the text box with the corner of the image. Ideally, I'd like the alignment to be independent of font size and image pixel size, but that might be asking a bit too much.

Finally, I'd like to achieve this with a grid of images, like the second example, below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
images = 4*[np.random.random((256,256))]

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(
    nrows=2, 
    ncols=2,
    top=1., 
    bottom=0., 
    right=1., 
    left=0., 
    hspace=0.,
    wspace=0.,
)
for g, i in zip(gs, range(len(images))):
    ax = plt.subplot(g)
    im = ax.imshow(
        images[i],
        cmap=plt.get_cmap("viridis")
    )
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.annotate(
        s = 'image title', 
        xy=(0, 0), 
        xytext=(0, 0), 
        va='top',
        ha='left',
        fontsize = 15,
        bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=1),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Using `clip_on = True` as an argument to the `ax.annotate` will clip the text box to the axes limits.  Perhaps that helps (?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to P-robot for the solution. The key part of the solution is that the annotation *text edge* is offset x and y by one pixel from the `xy` coordinate. Any extra padding used increases the necessary amount to compensate for this offset. The second grouping of arguments given to `ax.annotate`, below, are the relevant ones.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(np.random.random((256,256)), cmap=plt.get_cmap("viridis"))
ax.axis("off")

padding = 5
ax.annotate(
    s = 'image title', 
    fontsize = 12,

    xy=(0, 0), 
    xytext=(padding-1, -(padding-1)), 
    textcoords = 'offset pixels',
    bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=1, pad=padding),
    va='top',
    ha='left',
    )
plt.show()
```

[image: Aligned image]

Oddly, for the grid of four images, the offset in the x-direction did not require the subtraction of one pixel, which changes `xytext` to `xytext=(padding, -(padding-1))`.

[image: Aligned grid of four images]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused from the padding of the bounding box.  You can change the padding by passing the `pad` argument to the bounding box dictionary (for instance `pad = 0` will keep the box inside the axes).  I'm assuming you want some padding so it's probably best to set a padding argument and remove this from the position of the annotation (in units of pixels).

Comment: Thanks, you were exactly spot on. With no `xytext` offset, `pad=1` gives an aligned edge, so I have to account for any additional adding with `xytext`. I've added a solution based on my code fixed by your suggestion.